# Loop through background colors (for loop)

Tags: javascript, dom, loops, for-loop

I am trying to learn Javascript and the DOM. I would like to use a for loop to create alternative background colours for my text.

HTML:

```
<p> one </p>
<p> two </p>
<p> three </p>
<p> four </p>
<p> five </p>
```

Javascript:

```
var p = document.getElementByTagName(p);
var colors = ["red","green"];

 for(var i=0 ; i < p.length; i++) {
     p.style.background = colors;

 }
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/LMdXn/36/

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Well, what's wrong with the code you have now? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
for(var i=0 ; i < p.length; i++) {
     p[i].style.background = colors[i%2];

 }
```

`i%2` means the remainder or `i` (the loop variable) divided by 2. What you're doing is you're telling it to look at alternating places.

#### [Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X4EKJ/)

Worth mentioning, in new browsers [you don't need JavaScript to do this (CSS is enough)](http://jsfiddle.net/BUydW/)

[Here is a nice tutorial on arrays on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: That's great. Could I use colors.push(); to make the colours fill all the p elements?

Comment: I don't see how `colors.push()` does for you here (it adds an element to the colors array), but if what you mean is add items to the end of that array after creation then yes, you can.

Comment: Sorry. I mean because I only have two colours in the array, but five paragraphs. Rather than create more colors in the array, could I use just two, but still color all five <p> tags?

Comment: Yes, this is what the modulus operator does here (the %). It's the 'division remainder'. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6zfzfy7(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clear and simple way to achieve what you want, without clutter of extra unnecessary features:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var colors = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF"];
for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    paragraphs[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i % colors.length];
}
```

All it does is this:

1. Gets the array of app `<p>` elements on the page
2. Create the array of all colors (Red, Green, and Blue in this case)
3. Gives each element the next color in the array

It also makes sure it won't return `undefined` colors with the `i % colors.length` part, which is something you should always consider.

If all the paragraphs are in the same container, you can do this in CSS:

```
#container p:nth-child(3n+1)
{
    background-color: #F00;
}
#container p:nth-child(3n+2)
{
    background-color: #0F0;
}
#container p:nth-child(3n+3)
{
    background-color: #00F;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I used a loop so it could go to infinity theoretically. Would I always use the % remainder to achieve infinity, with only two items in the array?

Comment: You can't get to infinity, unless you have a loop checking for a condition that is never achieved, or a method calling itself without reasonable returns. The % (modulus) operator makes it so you never run out of colors to assign to a `<p>` in this example, by making the values wrap and restart at the beginning for each third iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9gVD/).

You have a few mistakes... mostly forgetting the `[i]` as in `p[i]`, also `getElementsByTagName` in plural.. I added more values to colors array so it won't go out of bounds (you can also use `%` (mod) as in `colors[i % colors.length]`)

Comment: Thanks. How comes p[i].style.background has an [i] after the p?

Comment: p is an array containing all `<p>` elements, you only want to change the current element's background.. p[i] is the current element

Comment: yep, look at my update: `colors[i % colors.length]` that way you don't go out of colors array bounds.. (you may have more `<p>` elements than colors).. [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqX4R/)

Comment: That's great. I've never used anything other than [i], [1], [2] etc in an array, I'll have to look up what that means :)

Comment: when you do `for(i=0;i<p.length;i++)` your basically saying: for every array cell in `p`, `i` holds the current key - then do something `p.length` (in our case 5) times. please accept my answer if helped you..